# What does "countable-fold" mean?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In the context of $\sigma$-algebras one finds the notion of "closed under *countable-fold* of operations".

What does "countable-fold" mean?

Are e.g.

$$A \cap B \cap C$$

$$A \cap (B \cup C)$$

countable-folds (one can "count" the operations)?

Comment: Saying that $\mathscr{A}$ is closed under countable-fold union and intersection, for instance, means that if $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$ is countable, then $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{A}$ and $\bigcap\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{A}$. *Countable* here means *finite or countably infinite*. In general it makes sense only for operations that are both associative and commutative.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But what does it refer to? The set of operations or the set of (some countable) elements?

Comment: The set of operands to which the operation is applied — the set $\mathscr{C}$ in my example.

Comment: An unary operation, one that applies to exactly one thing, is "one-fold". Like negation, for example. A binary operation like addition is "two-fold". A ternary operation, that applies to exactly three things, is "three-fold", for example I can't think of an example. A "countable-fold" operation applies to countably many things. Like taking the union of countably many sets. Or the supremum of countably many functions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So what's the union operation actually doing for countable sets? For e.g. sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$. Does it do it like: $a \cup b, a \cup d, b \cup c ...$?

Comment: @mavavilj: No: the union of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ is $\{a,b,c,d\}$. But we’re not talking about countable sets of points of the $\sigma$-algebra: we’re talking about countable *families* of sets of points.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, but how is the operation "countable-fold"? Why is $\{a,b\} \cup \{c,d\}$ a countable-fold operation?

Comment: @mavavilj: Ignore the specific term *countable-fold*, since it’s causing you so much trouble: it just means that if you apply the operation (here union or intersection) to countably many members of the algebra at once, you get a member of the algebra.

Comment: I think 'countable-fold' is horribly ugly (and 'countable-fold of' is just plain wrong). What's wrong with 'countably many'?

Comment: Or "countably operationable"? That way "countable" refers clearly to the operands, not the operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate? :P http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207031/definition-twofold-threefold-and-fourfold

Answer (score 2):

Saying that $\mathscr{A}$ is closed under countable-fold union and intersection, for instance, means that if $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$ is countable, then $\bigcup\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{A}$ and $\bigcap\mathscr{C}\in\mathscr{A}$. *Countable* here means *finite or countably infinite*. In general it makes sense only for operations that are both associative and commutative.

In other words, *countable-fold* refers to the number of operands to which the operation is applied. The family of open sets in a topological space is *closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions*; that means that if $\mathscr{F}$ is a *finite* family of open sets, then $\bigcap\mathscr{F}$ is open, and if $\mathscr{A}$ is *any* family of open sets, then $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ is open.

A $\sigma$-algebra is closed under *countable* unions and intersections; in your source this is expressed by saying that it’s closed under *countable-fold* unions and intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. You can "translate" the statement as follows:

> Let $I$ be any countable set, and let $A:I\to\Omega$ be a family indexed by $I$. Then
>   $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\in \Omega,\qquad\text{and}\qquad\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\in\Omega.$$

Comment: This is a pretty clear answer to me.

Comment: @mavavilj Thanks. The answer by Brian M. Scott is also interesting, now you've understood this definition.